# Except string datatype, not getting any columns populated through AIF Service

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a simple custom table in AX, for which i need to create a Web service so that data could be populated by an external system. I created a Document service with all the Axd* and Ax* objects involved. Next i wrote a simple console application to try populating some dummy data. Interesting thing is i can only get string data type columns populated. Int, Real, Date, Enums etc are not coming through.

In the code below, i am only getting StoreItemId and Barcode columns, as both are strings. Cost is real, ErrorType is Enum, DocketDate is date and none of them get any values. I have discussed this issue with many colleagues and none is aware whats happening. Does anyone know or could point me in some new direction? Thanks a lot.

PS - I have limited experience with AIF and if i am missing something fundamental, please excuse and do let me know. Thanks.

```
AxdEntity_MMSStagingSalesImport stagingSalesImport = new AxdEntity_MMSStagingSalesImport();
stagingSalesImport.StoreItemId = "9999";
stagingSalesImport.Barcode = "1234546";
stagingSalesImport.Cost = 22;
stagingSalesImport.ErrorType = AxdEnum_MMSImportErrorType.Posting;
stagingSalesImport.DocketDate = new DateTime(2014, 4, 4);
stagingSalesImport.IsDuplicate = AxdEnum_NoYes.Yes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying Klaas, i like your blog as well.

Should have responded earlier but i fixed the issue.
I didn't try Klaas's option but i had a look at the data policies for the inbound port and found that none of the columns were enabled. I enabled the ones i needed and made most of them required as well. And guess what, that worked. I was expecting that the columns should have been enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

For some types, you have to specify that you have set the values, so that AX knows the difference between a null value and a value that is set:

```
stagingSalesImport.Cost = 22;
stagingSalesImport.CostSpecified = true;
stagingSalesImport.ErrorType = AxdEnum_MMSImportErrorType.Posting;
stagingSalesImport.ErrorTypeSpecified = AxdEnum_MMSImportErrorType.Posting;
```